# No such table: tablename. - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm creating a search interface using UNION in multiple tables, whenever I search for a word the app closes and the error says that there no such tablename, although there is. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Here is my code.

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (searchText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_acc WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_filems WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_psu WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_shells WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_sic WHERE name LIKE ? " +
                        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id,name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_stp WHERE name LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{searchText.getText().toString() + "%" });
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), 
                R.layout.search_command_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"name", "desc"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.commandName, R.id.commandDesc}, 0);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else {

                }

        }



    });

}
```

Here is my logcat

> 12-04 01:19:47.145: E/SQLiteLog(19154): (1) no such table: comm_stp
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: comm_stp (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc
>   FROM comm_acc WHERE name LIKE ?1 UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS
>   name, desc AS desc FROM comm_filems WHERE name LIKE ?1 UNION SELECT
>   _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_psu WHERE name LIKE ?1 UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc FROM
>   comm_shells WHERE name LIKE ?1 UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name,
>   desc AS desc FROM comm_sic WHERE name LIKE ?1 UNION SELECT _id AS
>   _id,name AS name, desc AS desc FROM comm_stp WHERE name LIKE ?1 12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) 12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:886)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:497)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   com.example.ttg.CommandList$1.onTextChanged(CommandList.java:78) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7330) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7392) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9006)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:674)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:437)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 12-04 01:19:47.177:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 12-04 01:19:47.177:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   12-04 01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 12-04
>   01:19:47.177: E/AndroidRuntime(19154):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I don't see the create table code. But I suggest you uninstall your app and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since your exception is:

```
  no such table: comm_stp
```

Check your database, you don´t have any table with name: `comm_stp`

Comment: There is a table name called comm_stp. Whenever I remove the comm_stp from the query, the error will say no such table: comm_sic.